# Render view after loading js on blade file using laravel view render function

Tags: javascript, laravel, formbuilder

We are creating a api that loads the html content of view page in controller using laravel render function. We are able to get the html content. But there is js script running on view file that render some html to the view. That html is not getting loaded.

```
controller : 
       try{
            $return = [
                'status' => 'fail',
                'msg' => 'Unable to load form',
            ];
            $currentUser = Auth::user();
            $form = DynamicForm::where('id', $id)->first();
            $renderContent = view('form.render_form')->with(compact('form'))->render();
            $return = [
                'status' => 'success',
                'msg' => 'Form loaded successfully',
                'data' => $renderContent
            ];
            return $return;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Log::error('renderForm() : '.$e->getMessage());
            return $return;
        }
```

Any help will be deeeply appreciated.

Comment: if I've understood this correctly, you have some `JS` code in the `form.render_form` view that you want to execute once the rendered view is sent back to the browser ?

Comment: before rendering the view js must be excecuted so that all html is loaded by js and then sent to the view as  render

Comment: You can only run the JS AFTER you have sent it to the client browser.